# Add arrow to MatTooltip

Tags: angular, angular-material, tooltip

I would like to add an arrow below with MatTooltip on Angular 16.But for some reason overriding the Material with a pseudo element for an arrow doesnt work as suggested in many posts.
Here is my code :

```
<th class="value-style" matTooltip={{tile.tooltip}} [matTooltipPosition]='tooltipPosition' matTooltipClass="TooltipClass">{{tile.count}}</th>
```

In Scss

```
.homeTooltipClass {
  .mdc-tooltip__surface {
    background: rgba($color:black, $alpha: 1) !important;
    background-color: black;
    color: white !important;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    max-width: 200px !important;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px black;    
  }
}
```

```
 public tooltipPosition: TooltipPosition = "above";
```

Comment: please provide a stackblitz examle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really I can not imagine how you draw the "arrow", but you need take account three things

1. The .css should be in a "global" style (e.g. in the styles.css of
   your application. Material angular create the tooltip in a cdk-panel
   "outside" the application.
2. You should indicate overflow:visible to your tooltip

   ```
   .mat-tooltip.TooltipClass{
     overflow: visible;
   }
   ```
3. An example of draw a bottom arrow

   ```
   .mat-tooltip.TooltipClass::after {
     content: " ";
     position: absolute;
     top: 100%; /* At the bottom of the tooltip */
     left: 50%;
     margin-left: -5px;
     border-width: 5px;
     border-style: solid;
     border-color: rgba(97, 97, 97, .9) transparent transparent transparent;
   }
   ```

A [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wk6vsw-zstwxt?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftab-group-basic-example.html,src%2Fstyles.scss)

NOTE: in material v16, the class should be `mat-mdc-tooltip`